# How can I disable parent menu link to be non-clickable?

Tags: navigation

Nolink,None,Separator and other things does not work when added to URL path.
Have also Installed menu module but that did not help.
Its Drupal 7.

Thank you for your co-operation!

Comment: have you tried special menu item drupal 7 https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Special Menu Items module. You can add menu items that are placeholders or separators but aren't clickable. It is found on the drupal module site: https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items

Answer (score 0):

you can also use simplify menu module and then in your menuname.html.twig you can only print the menu name and skip link for parent